# Why is my MRTK Android AR App background black?

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, mrtk, windows-mixed-reality

I started a project on Unity version 2019.4.24f1, imported MRTK 2.6.1 foundation, tools, etc and set everything up according to this guide:

https://microsoft.github.io/MixedRealityToolkit-Unity/Documentation/CrossPlatform/UsingARFoundation.html

The App starts and shows the elements that I placed in the testscene (buttons, etc), but the background of the app is black and there is no camera access question from my android system.

The device I am testing on is a Oneplus 3T and the minumum SDK requirements are met.
How can I get this to work? I will post my MRTK and Player Settings below:

MRTK Settings:
[image]

Player Settings: [image]
[image]

XR Settings: (Note that If I activate AR Core tick, it displays an error)
[image]

Error when AR Core is ticked:
[image]

Packages:

[image]

Comment: We find that the version of ARCore XR Plugin in your project (2.1.2) is lower than the version specified in the doc (2.1.11). Could you upgrade it in the UPM first and try to deploy again? Besides, both conceptual docs and API references have moved to learn.microsoft.com, please refer this doc to configure your project:[How to configure MRTK for iOS and Android](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/mrtk-unity/features/cross-platform/using-ar-foundation)

Comment: If I use these versions on my smartphone, it tells me "You must have the latest version of ARCore installed to use this application"
It then changes to the ARCore Page in the playstore and it tells me that it is not compatible with my smartphone. I have a oneplus 3T with Android 9 and cannot find something about the minimum requirements.
 However, if I use the latest 2.x versions, I dont get this message. It just asks for my camera and then stays with a black screen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turned out that my phone is just too old and doesn't support ARCore. The app worked on another phone just fine.

Answer (score 2):

If you follow the steps in this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/mrtk-unity/supported-devices/using-ar-foundation#building-a-scene-for-android-and-ios-devices) to configure your project, but the Android device camera does not work with MRTK, it is recommended you double-check the following points:

1. Minimum API Level (Project Setting>Player>Android>Other Setting) should higher than Android 8.0.
2. After installing `AR Foundation` and `ARCore XR Plugin` packages, don’t forget to **update the MRTK UnityAR scripting defines by invoking the menu item**: Mixed Reality Toolkit > Utilities > UnityAR > Update Scripting Defines.
3. Make sure you have unchecked the `ARCore Supported` in the `Legacy built-in XR support`: Project Setting> Player>Android>XR Settings.
4. And then, nav to `XR Plug-In Management` and check the `ARCore` under the Android.
5. `Vulkan` Graphics API is not currently supported, please make sure to delete this and keep only `OpenGLES3`: Project Setting>Player>Android>Other Setting>Graphics APIs

Comment: I have made sure I followed every step and I indeed had Android 7 set as minimum Version. If I Build & Run, the app starts and tells me "You must have the latest version of ARCore installed to use this application" It then changes to the ARCore Page in the playstore and it tells me that it is not compatible anymore with my smartphone. I have a oneplus 3T with Android 9. Is there anything else I can try except testing on another phone?

Comment: The minimum Version should be Android 8.0, not Android 7. For the ARCore version and PlayStore issue, I am not an expert in this technology.

Answer (score 0):

The screen is black is because the camera access is not granted.

Check if your manifest file has the camera access permission.

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-permission-element

Comment: I could not find the appmanifest in my unity, so I just used the Unity permission api (or so its called). It doesnt matter the ARCore Version, I got asked once, i allowed camera but the backgroudn stays black. I added ```#if PLATFORM_ANDROID
                Permission.RequestUserPermission(Permission.Camera);
        #endif``` to my void start() of a script in the scene